# Given a Python method, how to get its class?

Tags: python, oop, methods

Suppose I have this class:

```py
class Foo():
    def foo_method(self):
        pass
```

Now suppose I have an object `foo = Foo()`.
I can pass `foo.foo_method` around as argument to a function.
`foo.foo_method.__qualname__` returns the string representing the method's "full name":
`"Foo.foo_method"`.
*What if I want to get `Foo`, the class itself, from `foo.foo_method`?*

The solution I came up with is:

```py
def method_class(method):
    return eval(method.__qualname__.split(".")[0])
```

Is there a less "dirty" way of achieving this?

Comment: maybe `dir(foo)` or `help(foo)` print either of those and try

Comment: Have you looked at `__self__` of `foo_method`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instance that a bound method is bound to, is stored as the `__self__` attribute. Thus:

```py
class Foo:
    def foo_method(self):
        pass

foo = Foo()
assert foo.foo_method.__self__.__class__ is Foo
```

Answer (score 1):

The following might do what you want:

```python
    ##########################################################
    class Klassy:
        def methy(arg):
            pass
        
    insty = Klassy()
    
    funky = insty.methy
    
    ##########################################################
    
    insty_jr = funky.__self__        
            
    Klassy_jr = type(insty_jr)
    
    print(Klassy_jr)
```